# Jade mixin requires extra element

Tags: pug, codekit

**This compiles** but if I remove the `div` at the very end there, it throws an error. I am using codekit for compilation. What am I not getting here? Why does that extra `div` matter?

```
mixin ListItemDetail(labels,values)
    .listItemSection
        .listItemDetailWrap
            .listItemDetail #{labels[0]} :
            .listItemDetail &nbsp;#{values[0]}
        .listItemDetailWrap
            .listItemDetail #{labels[1]} :
            .listItemDetail &nbsp;#{values[1]}
        .listItemDetailWrap
            .listItemDetail #{labels[2]} :
            .listItemDetail &nbsp;#{values[2]}

mixin ListItem()
    .listItem
        .listItemSection
            h2 48 barrels of Kansas Common by 00/00/0000
            small Ellsworth County, Kasas, 38.4500&deg; N 96.5333&deg; W

        mixin ListItemDetail(['Start Date', 'End Date', 'Pickup Deadline'], ['00/00/0000',  '00/00/0000',   '00/00/0000'])
        mixin ListItemDetail(["Bulletin",   "Grade",    "Join Deadline"],   ["Plains",      "Light Crude",  "00/00/0000"])
        mixin ListItemDetail(["API",        "BS&W",     "Sulfur"],          ["48&deg;",     "4%",           "0.1%"])        

        div
```

this is the error that occurs in the codekit log if that final `div` is missing:

```
/Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/jade/lib/runtime.js:173
  throw err;
        ^
Error: /Users/isaac/Radiant/DemandPoint/dpe-grails/web-app/jade/Elements/ListItem.jade:23
    21|         mixin ListItemDetail(["API",        "BS&W",     "Sulfur"],          ["48&deg;",     "4%",           "0.1%"])        
    22| 
  > 23|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. In your example code you are not utilizing the mixin `ListItem`, though. Maybe some indentation is wrong. You could even simplify your code and use [iteration](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#iteration):

```
mixin ListItemDetail(labels,values)
  each label,i in labels
    .listItemSection
      .listItemDetailWrap
        .listItemDetail #{label} :
        .listItemDetail &nbsp;#{values[i]}

mixin ListItem
  .listItem
    .listItemSection
      h2 48 barrels of Kansas Common by 00/00/0000
      small Ellsworth County, Kasas, 38.4500&deg; N 96.5333&deg; W

    mixin ListItemDetail(['Start Date', 'End Date', 'Pickup Deadline'], ['00/00/0000',  '00/00/0000',   '00/00/0000'])
    mixin ListItemDetail(["Bulletin",   "Grade",    "Join Deadline"],   ["Plains",      "Light Crude",  "00/00/0000"])
    mixin ListItemDetail(["API",        "BS&W",     "Sulfur"],          ["48&deg;",     "4%",           "0.1%"])

mixin ListItem // use your mixin here
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplification +1! Another file is consuming this mixin, which is why it is not there. It could also be an issue with my version of jade. The downside to using codekit, it that version is static and I cannot update it.

Comment: Something about your answer fixed it. I must of had a stray indent or something.